# Use math font for TikZ arrow labels

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-mode, labels, tikz-styles

I am trying to make arrow labels look like they are written in math mode. This is what I have: 
[image]

This is what I want [image],

I tried to use different fonts but without success. This is my code:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=0.5mm, bend angle=45]                                                                                                                                          
  \tikzstyle{place} = [ circle,draw=black,fill=black,thick ]                                                                                                                                                                    
  \tikzstyle{surd} = [circle]                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  \tikzstyle{pre} = [ <-,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt, >=stealth', semithick]                                                                                                                                                    
  \tikzstyle{every node} = [font=\normalsize\itshape]                                                                                                                                                                           

  \node[place] (first) {};                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  \node[place] (second) [right=of first] {}                                                                                                                                                                                     
    edge [pre,bend right]  node [above] {$a$} (first)                                                                                                                                                                           
    edge [pre,bend left]  node [below] {$b$} (first);                                                                                                                                                                           
  \node[place] (third) [right=of second] {}                                                                                                                                                                                     
    edge [pre]  node [above] {$c$} (second);                                                                                                                                                                                    
  \node[surd] (surd)  [right=of third] {\Large$\surd$}                                                                                                                                                                          
    edge [pre] node [above] {$d$} (third);                                                                                                                                                                                      
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Which class are you using? Beamer perhaps?

Comment: BTW: do not use `tikzstyle`, see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino yes beamer class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the Beamer class you may want to use:

```
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
```

to render in serif font only the math. If one does not want to type every time the `$` to enter in math mode, it is possible to create a style for that:

```
\tikzset{math mode/.style={%
    execute at begin node=$,%
    execute at end node=$,%
  }
}
```

Then, by grouping all nodes in a `scope`:

```
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={math mode}]
...
\end{scope}
```

the style will be applied "locally".

An example with the `math mode` style active:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
Some text in sans serif font. Math, like:
\begin{equation}
x+y=100
\end{equation}
is rendered in serif font.
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=0.5mm, bend angle=45]                                                                                                                                          
  \tikzset{place/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=black,thick}}
  \tikzset{surd/.style={circle}}                   
  \tikzset{pre/.style={ <-,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt, >=stealth', semithick}} 
  % to avoid using every time dollars for math mode
  \tikzset{math mode/.style={%
      execute at begin node=$,%
      execute at end node=$,%
    }
  }

  \node[place] (first) {};
  % using a scope to not apply the new math mode definition to all nodes
  % as it might not be the desired behaviour
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={math mode}]
  \node[place] (second) [right=of first] {}
    edge [pre,bend right]  node [above] {a} (first)
    edge [pre,bend left]  node [below] {b} (first);
  \node[place] (third) [right=of second] {}
      edge [pre]  node [above] {c} (second);
  \node[surd] (surd)  [right=of third] {\Large\surd}
    edge [pre] node [above] {d} (third);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A complete example without the style `math mode`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
Some text in sans serif font. Math, like:
\begin{equation}
x+y=100
\end{equation}
is rendered in serif font.
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=0.5mm, bend angle=45]                                                                                                                                          
  \tikzset{place/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=black,thick}}
  \tikzset{surd/.style={circle}}                   
  \tikzset{pre/.style={ <-,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt, >=stealth', semithick}}
  %\tikzset{every node/.append style={font=\normalsize\itshape}} %useless in this case 

  \node[place] (first) {};
  \node[place] (second) [right=of first] {}
    edge [pre,bend right]  node [above] {$a$} (first)
    edge [pre,bend left]  node [below] {$b$} (first);
  \node[place] (third) [right=of second] {}
      edge [pre]  node [above] {$c$} (second);
  \node[surd] (surd)  [right=of third] {\Large$\surd$}
    edge [pre] node [above] {$d$} (third);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: A note: to go in new line you don't need 220 spaces (on average) at the end of the line.

Comment: One question: is  \tikzstyle = [something/.style = ... ] ?

Comment: What about non beamer environments ? I might need to create an article from this presentation and reuse there my pictures. Is this similar?

Comment: And what if I ommit $a$ and write only a ? Will it also work ? (sorry for so many questions)

Comment: `tikzstyle` is obsolete, as per [my previous comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131831/use-math-font-for-tikz-arrow-labels/131837?noredirect=1#comment297557_131831); second: for the article you don't have any problems in copy and paste the pictures' code: they will use automatically serif font (unless you specified something different, but that's not the default behaviour).

Comment: No, you need `$...$` otherwise you are not in math mode.

Comment: so it si not possible to set a font looking like math mode for tikz and write not in math mode ?

Comment: No, because math mode brings features that italic font doesn't have: spaces around the operators, for instance.